# How to Parse String SUN 2 FEB to closest date to TODAY matching the day of week and month combination

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Is there a way to parse a `string which is missing year` to `datetime` but we know its the `datetime` is nearest date to NOW which matches `Day of Week` and `Day of Month` combination. Example string are

```
TUE 4 FEBRUARY 1 PM// 
WED 05 FEBRUARY 0100 PM//
FRI 21 FEBRUARY 100 PM//
```

Currently as I know that the dates fall the year 2020 so I am adding "2020" And using the follwing statement

```
var str = "05/12/" +  "2020" + "0100 PM"
/*str is obtained by string manipulation as I know the year*/
DateTime dt;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(toplinks[i].iDate,
                   "dd/MM/yyyy hhmm tt",
                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                   DateTimeStyles.None,
                   out dt))
```

Additional complications are that the day of Month can be either `'dd'` or simply `'d'`. And timespan can be any combination of `'hhmm tt'` or `'hmm tt'` or `'h tt'` and the timespan falls between `"10:00AM"` to `"07:00PM"`

Comment: you have a problem, what about 3rd of March? that would be 2019, not 2020, correct? then you may need to compare the day and month with todays day and month and check if it is current year or the previous one (DateTime.now() may help or check if there is a method such as GetCurrentYear())

Comment: What logic do you want when the day+month *doesn't* fall into the current year?  You say "nearest", but do you truly mean *nearest*? or do you mean *last* or *next*?  Examples: `FRI 1 JANUARY` - is that 2016 or 2021?  How about `TUE 1 JANUARY` - is that 2019 or 2030?   What if they are equidistant?  To determine the distance between now and the possible dates, are you measuring just years or the full date?  It would be helpful if you tried to show an example of how you're attempting this part of the problem in your code.  The current code only adds 2020.  Thanks.